# Hide the 'Unidentified Index' warnings

Tags: php, post

I'm getting tons of these warnings popping up on my site when I submit a form (I'm grabbing them with a $_POST).

```
Notice: Undefined index: FuelPurch in C:\xampp\htdocs\daniel\ShellySite\controller\php\submit_form.php on line 9
```

What's the best way to hide them/make them not show up? It's not an issue to me if some of the fields aren't filled in, I just don't want them to show up.

I've tried something like this...

```
    if(isset($_POST['FuelPurch'])){
        $FuelP=$_POST['FuelPurch'];
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work...

EDIT: Nevermind, I was editing the mobile version of my site without being aware so I wasn't seeing the results I wanted when viewing it from my PC. For clarification, my posted code segment there does work.

Comment: If you are using `$FuelP` somewhere afterwards, assign some value to it. Use `$FuelP=isset($_POST['FuelPurch']) ? $_POST['FuelPurch'] : '';`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use
[`error reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to shut these errors off.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

But curiously the `isset` approach you mentioned should actually work and is cleaner as well.

Maybe you used `$FuleP` later on, which will be undefined and thus throw the same error if `$_POST['FuelPurch']` is undefined. In this case try:

```
$FuelP=0; // Suitable default value that will be used if no value is posted
if (isset($_POST['FuelPurch'])) $FuelP=$_POST['FuelPurch'];
```

This way `$FuelP` will be defined no matter what.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, turns out my code was working, I was just editing the mobile version of my site by accident so I didn't see the changes I was looking for when viewing it from my desktop!

Comment: For `E_NOTICE` I find that statement arguable, in any case I mentioned that the `isset` approach would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following line on the top of the file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

However, the `isset()` method should work and it's indicated to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Just write `if isset` in right place. Don't disable error reporting! Show us code if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Or on one-lines statements you can just add "@" at the begining of the line